# Is this apply method defined correctly?

Tags: scala

When I run below code the apply method is not being called :

Java :

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        new parallel.TestData();
    }

}
```

Scala :

```
package parallel

class TestData {
    def apply() = {
      println("in apply method ")
    }
}
```

If I use :

```
new parallel.TestData().apply();
```

then the apply method is called correctly but should the apply() method not be implicitly invoked from above code ? Is the apply method not implemented correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, there is a difference between a *constructor* and the *apply* method. It seems that you expect the apply method to act like a constructor. However, the constructor is a method named `def this(...)`. Your are hence not defining a constructor.

The apply method can be called by using a name just like any other method (`.apply()`) or by using parantheses (`()`). After having created a new instance of your class, you still need to call the apply method.

You can thus either **create a new instance of your class and call `apply`**:

```
new parallel.TestData()()
//                   ^  ^---- apply method
//                   |------- constructor
```

Or you can **implement an object instead of a class**:

```
object TestData {
    def apply() = {
      println("in apply method ")
    }
}
parallel.TestData()
```

**Update**: When calling Scala code from Java, you would have to stick to the first method. As Java does not add syntactic sugar for the apply method, you are left with the option of an explicit call: `new parallel.TestData().apply()`.

Comment: the object cannot be instantiated from java since its an object and not a class ?